# Error when setting up phpunit tests with wp-cli scaffold

Tags: plugins, wp-cli, unit-tests

I am trying to figure out the setup for unit tests for wordpress plugins. I am using Ubuntu. So far I have:

- Local WordPress Installation
- WP-CLI up and running
- Installed phpunit
- used wp scaffold command to generate unit test files

When I now try and run the phpunit command I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/tmp/wordpress//wp-includes/class-       phpmailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in  /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/mock-mailer.php on line 2
```

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/tmp/wordpress//wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/mock-mailer.php on line 2

This is my wp --info:

```
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php5
PHP version:    5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4
php.ini used:   /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 1.0.0
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-setting-up-testing-suite/

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows. Can't find much info on this anywhere.

Comment: I recently switched to MacOS for all WordPress development. Have not figured it out on Windows yet either.

Comment: I've found that the [tutorial](https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-setting-up-testing-suite/) cited lacks some key instructions, only one of which I've figured out.  It does not say to install svn (subversion) before starting.   Once I did that I had to run the lines that call `svn co...` by hand. What is not at all made clear and remains unknown is how the tutorial's database knows their plugin is installed.  When I checked my test database it had none of the settings of an activated plugin. Tutorial may be necessary but is insufficient for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, open wp-tests-config.php and change the ABSPATH with absolute path to your TEMP folder. For example:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', 'C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Temp/wordpress/' );
```

I changed this and phpunit worked! This code is on line 7 in %TEMP%/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php

Comment: How about Linux or MacOS ? I am using Mac OS and saw this issue. Do you know how to fix it ?